# how to solve the object reference not set to an instance of an object?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In my c# MVVM program. I set one observable collections. And I add to the image from the list. But i get Object reference not set to an instance of an object error.

```
   private ObservableCollection<SpecialAttractionImageModel> _SpecialAttractionImageModelObj = new ObservableCollection<SpecialAttractionImageModel>();

    public ObservableCollection<SpecialAttractionImageModel> SpecialAttractionImageModelObj
            {
                get { return _SpecialAttractionImageModelObj; }
                set
                {
                    _SpecialAttractionImageModelObj = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("SpecialAttractionImageModelObj");
                }
            }

foreach (String file in fd.FileNames)
                    {
                        FileInfo currentFile = new FileInfo(file);
                        _SpecialAttractionImageModelObj.Add(new SpecialAttractionImageModel()
                        {
                            AttractionImageGid = "new",
                            SpecialAttracionImagePath = file,
                            IsChecked=false
                        });
                    }
```

Comment: you may want to show the complete exception details, it is not easy to see from the code you are providing

Comment: Yes, we especially need to know what line throws the exception.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio, during debug hover over each variable on that line and see which one is null.

Comment: Either `_SpecialAttractionImageModelObj` or `file`.

Comment: Why do you need a setter on the observablecollection, this is not normally needed. Because you have a private initializer, some code must set it to null explicitely.

Answer (score -1):

Object is not initialized, maybe  `OnPropertyChanged("SpecialAttractionImageModelObj");` is the cause.

Stack Trace would help you figure out where this is happening.